# Is the projection on a convex set closer to the points of the set?

Tags: geometry, optimization

Consider a general norm on $\mathbb R^n$ and a convex and compact set K.

Let $P_K(x) \in \arg\min_{y \in K} \lVert y - x \rVert$.

Is it true that any point in K is closer to $P_K(x)$ than to x? I.e.,
$\lVert P_K(x) - y \rVert \le \lVert x - y \rVert$ for each $y \in K$?

This is true for the norm 2, but what about other norms?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily: see $K=\{0\}\times [-1,1]$ and $x=(1,0)$ in $(\Bbb R^2,\lVert\bullet\rVert_\infty)$. Then, $\arg\min_{y\in K} \lVert y-x\rVert_\infty=K$, but $\sup_{a,b\in K}\lVert a-b\rVert_\infty=2>1$

Comment: Thanks. What about if the projection is unique? And do you think one can build also an example with a norm p with p< \infty?

Comment: Right! Strong convexity of the norm could perhaps make the statement true.

Comment: @Giovanni Yeah, I was thinking about that too, but I have other stuff to do now.